# Is there a way to useState for dynamic form fields pulled from a server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating a next application that pulls the form fields from a firestore collection. The form fields can be changed on the database and the changes reflect on the form. I render the text fields dynamically like below.

```js
{ 
    formfield && formfield
        .filter((items => items.type === 'text'))
        .sort((a,b) => (a.order_by > b.order_by) ? 1 : -1)
        .map(item => {
            return (
                <div className="input-field mb-40" key={form_item.id}>
                    <input 
                        placeholder={form_item.place_holder}
                        type="text" 
                        id={ item.item_id }
                        required = {item.required}
                        onChange={e => setItem(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="full_name" className="active fnt-16">
                        { form_item.label }
                    </label>
                </div>
            )
        })
}
```

The challenge I am facing is with handling the `onChange`. I would like to use the `useState` hook but don't know how to loop through it and update based on the field ID which is acquired from the database.

I have tried

```js
textfields && textfields.map((text, index) => {
    let textF = text.item_id;
    let setTextF= 'set' + textF;

    [text, setTextF ] = useState('')   
})

But this doesn't work as it says I can't assign string to `setTextF`. 

Does anyone know how to go about this?
```

Comment: Put your `useState` outside the loop.  Then just use `setText(textF)`.  Not sure what you were trying to do with this line: `let setTextF= 'set' + textF;` but you shouldn't redefine `setText`.
`

Comment: How can I do that, If I put it outside the loop, I will only have one state called TextF and that will change anytime I make changes to any of the fields. I use let setTextF= 'set' + textF; to dynamically create the current state and updater function

Comment: That is correct.  You should only have one state.  If you want a collection of all of the results, `map` is already providing that for you.  You can put the entire result into state and map over it from there, but at that point, I'm not sure why you would use `useState` at all.

Comment: If it is not too much to ask, could you please help with a code snippet of how to do that, I am really stuck on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going on the assumption that you want to use `useState` to hold form data until you resubmit it.  You've already got the code to build the form, so I think you want to hold an object containing all the k/v pairs.  So at the top of your component:

```
const [text, setText] = useState({})
```

Then you can set the defaults from the server:

```
textfields && textfields.map((text, index) =>{
    setText({...text, {index: text.item_id}}) // not really sure what you want here
})
```

Now you've built up an object that holds the state of your form.  To change it:

```
onChange={e => setText({...text, {index: e.target.value}})}
```

I'm not really clear what your state object is supposed to look like based on what you have here, but this is the general pattern I think you're looking for.  It's conventional to use the field names as keys so you get an object that's like `{name: 'Joe', email: 'joe@joe.com'}` or whatever.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. when I try it, it gives me an error that says infinite loop. When i bring it down to onChange={e => setText({...text, index: e.target.value})}, when I change any textfield, it updates a state called Index. the field that I update overrides the previous state

Comment: Sounds like your call is in a `useEffect`.  You have other structural issues here that go beyond the scope of your original question.

Comment: Try not setting your state with results of your fetch and simply mapping over it to create your initial render.  Then use the state to only only hold the dirty form state.